# displayDialogAsync api showing alert before opening dialogue view

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to do OAuth integration in my application.

As part of the oauth flow, opening oauth url with dialogueAsync api as below :

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, {width: 100, height: 100}, function (asyncResult) {
                self.oauthWindow = asyncResult.value;
                if (asyncResult.status != 'succeeded') {
                    self.oauthWindow && self.oauthWindow.close();
                } 
            });
```

Also added domains in manifest file under AppDomain section :

```
<AppDomains>
        <AppDomain>https://app.xeninc.us</AppDomain>
        <AppDomain>https://sf.xenovusapps.net</AppDomain>
        <AppDomain>https://login.microsoftonline.com</AppDomain>
        <AppDomain>https://accounts.zoho.com</AppDomain>
        <AppDomain>https://login.salesforce.com</AppDomain>
        <AppDomain>https://account.box.com</AppDomain>
        <AppDomain>https://www.dropbox.com</AppDomain>
        <AppDomain>https://accounts.google.com</AppDomain>
        <AppDomain>https://login.live.com</AppDomain>
        <AppDomain>https://secure.sharefile.com</AppDomain>
    </AppDomains>
```

It is throwing below alert with message like below : 
[image]
Note:  This is happening in browsers only. Working fine in native apps
How to suppress that window ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This alert occurs by design as a necessary workaround for pop-up blocking settings that most browsers have. Please let us know if you have anymore questions.

Comment: Can we customise the message inthat pop up? Will office app store allows this to publish app?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible. However office app store will allow the app to be published.